# xgboost get_fscore() or get_score() returning less number of columns

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

I am trying to plot the feature importance using xgboost.
Below code shows the problem.
`len(dtrain.feature_names), 
len(model.get_score().values()), 
len(model.get_fscore().values())
(289, 269, 269)`

What is happening to rest 20 columns when I am trying to fetch the score.
Am I missing something. I am pretty much naive on this.

Answer (score 3):

Those 20 features (columns) never got selected in the gradient boosted decision trees. In other words, the XGBoost model is not using those 20 features.

Comment: Is it possible that the algorithm is dropping the feature on its own. I don't think its happening that way.

Comment: The algorithm is not "dropping" those 20 features, but has ended up not to utilize the information in them when constructing the decision trees. If you would like to increase the probability for a feature to be selected, increase the value of [`colsample_bytree`](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/doc/parameter.md#parameters-for-tree-booster) parameter. You can always make an experiment and train the model without those features. The accuracy of the model should stay somewhat same but not exactly the same because of the randomness of XGBoost.